# Ohm's Law gives me different values compared to the practical experiment with a multimeter - can you explain why?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, measurements, short-circuits

I am studying physics in high school and am trying to understand electronics.

Using Ohms law I calculated VIRP values for a simple circuit with three 1000 ohm resistors and a 9V battery. I then set up the same circuit on a breadboard and tested the Voltage and current using a multimeter but the values seem to be significantly different. For example, was expecting the total current to be 0.027A but the multimeter shows 2A

Not sure where I've gone wrong, can you explain? Pictures below show VIRP tables and the breadboard with the circuit

btw am at home due to pandemic therefore asking you guys instead of my teacher

[image: breadboard]

[image: virp tables - calculated and practical]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right scale?

Comment: On your diagram, show how you wired the ammeter into the circuit.

Comment: @DavidWhite Ive added a picture which shows where I connected the ammeter to get the total current.

Comment: @BobD the multimeter is auto ranging and the units were amps

Comment: @DavidWhite to check current of resisters I placed the multimeter across the resistors

Comment: @kINGAdAm OH NO!!. You placed the multimeter ACROSS the battery?

Comment: @BobD yes.. sounds very bad? btw nothing blew up! its a 9v battery

Comment: Thanks @SolomonSlow, thankfully nothing blew up... so after a bit of googling I have to make a break in the circuit and then connect the multimeter? btw How could I test current across a resistor?

Comment: There is no current _across_ a resistor. Current is _through_ a resistor. You measure the current by (1) disconnect the battery, (2) setting the meter to its (A) setting, (3) connect the meter _in series_ with the resistor, and (4) connect the battery.

Comment: Thanks @SolomonSlow I tried and now getting the right readings! ill tick yours as an answer if you want

Comment: @kINGAdAm, there is a rule of thumb for circuits.  ALWAYS place an ammeter in series with the circuit element you are trying to get an amp reading through, and ALWAYS place a volt meter in parallel with the circuit element that you are trying to get the voltage drop across.  You placed  your ammeter in parallel with the battery, so you measured full current flow through the electrical resistance of the battery, which is NOT what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you really connected the ampmeter like your sketch you should be happy it was not destroyed. What it measures in this position is the current the batterie gives in a shortcut A ampmeter must always be in the circuit, so between the batterie and the resistors,
Your ammeter is connected as a voltmeter.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already aware, you should not have connected the ammeter across the battery terminals. Fortunately, you didn't destroy the meter. So, you may ask, what current were you measuring?

Since the input resistance of the ammeter is  much less than the parallel combination of the three resistors, which is nominally 333 Ohms, that parallel resistance can be ignored. That means the current you were measuring is approximately the current that the internal battery emf (nominal 9 V) was delivering through the series combination of the internal resistance of the battery, $R_b$, and the input resistance of the ammeter, $R_{m}$ or

$$I=\frac{9}{R_{b}+R_{m}}$$

Hope this helps.